# Firebase + Angular - rules .read != null, still can view $firebaseArray without auth.

Tags: angularjs, security, firebase, rules

This should be simple as pie but ... anyways!

I have a little angular app that uses firebase.

In my firebase rules I have

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

So no access to should be allowed to the data. 
Now in my angular app I have a controller that tries to load in the data

```
.controller('loginCtrl', function ($firebaseArray, $scope) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://<url>.firebaseio.com/child');
    var list = $firebaseArray(ref);

    list.$loaded().then(function() {
        console.log(list)//this shows all the data and shouldnt!!!
    }, function(){
        console.log('no list found')
    });
});
```

Now according to everything I have read, the rules I have above are correct.
Is there something obvious that I am missing? I have searched for an answer none can be found. Any help is appreciated before I go insane.

Best.

Comment: I just quickly added `".read": "auth != null"` to one of my own test apps and I get no data (and proper error messages) immediately after that. Are there any more steps you're taking? It's going to be hard for me to reproduce the problem otherwise. 
`

Comment: Hi Frank, the issue seems to have resolved itself. I have no idea why it works now. Is it a propagation thing? Should be instant. Perhaps I had something cached. Getting grips with firebase ATM. Anyways thank you very much for offering your help. Have a good Friday.

Comment: Thanks Ant, great to hear that it now works. I'm voting to close based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the rules on the child level.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "child": {
            ".read": "auth != null",
            ".write": "auth != null"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I managed to get the above example working in the end.